# How to find parent closest anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change background color of an anchor tag. And to find this anchor tag I have a span with its id. Then how can I find this anchor tag. Html code is below

```
<li class="fa-2x lesson_strand active">
    <a onclick="window.open('/wwtb/api/viewer.pl?uid=demo_user&cid=1&wid=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&role=Student','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')" href="#">
        <b class="fa_text">Domain 4.OA Cluster 1 Quiz (Homework)</b>
    </a>
    <a onclick="window.open('/ePC/ePlannerAssessment.do?isbn=9780544349179&isSoar=0&toolType=12&uniqueID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&resourceBUID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&nextGenTool=WB%20HTTP/1.1','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')"
    href="#">
        <span id="assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1" class="assignButton" onclick="assignclicksToButton(event)">Assign</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I am trying to change color of first anchor tag and I have only span id. How can I do that . Please help.

Thanks !

Comment: code is missing? the function you are calling.

Comment: `document.getElementById('assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1').closest('a');`

Comment: when on **page load, click, on mouseevents**?

Comment: A jQuery method's not gonna work on a plain JS element, @Jaromanda X.

Comment: @Shikkediel - I'll remember that next time ... oh ... wait  `.closest` is a  HTMLElement method ... p.s. **IE must die**

Comment: Well, alright then... if you want to be experimental. Not seeing the point here though. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `.closest()` ([jQuery docs link](https://api.jquery.com/closest/))

```
$(this).closest('a');
```

From the API docs:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

use [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) then [`.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) methods `$("#assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1").parent().prev().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});`

```js
$("#assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1").parent().prev().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="fa-2x lesson_strand active">
  <a onclick="window.open('/wwtb/api/viewer.pl?uid=demo_user&cid=1&wid=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&role=Student','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')" href="#">
    <b class="fa_text">Domain 4.OA Cluster 1 Quiz (Homework)</b>
  </a>
  <a onclick="window.open('/ePC/ePlannerAssessment.do?isbn=9780544349179&isSoar=0&toolType=12&uniqueID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&resourceBUID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&nextGenTool=WB%20HTTP/1.1','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')"
  href="#">
    <span id="assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1" class="assignButton" onclick="assignclicksToButton(event)">Assign</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `closest` `li` and then `find` the `first` `a` of this `li`. Hope the code snippet given below will help you.

```js
$('#assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1').closest('li')
.find('a:first').css('background-color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="fa-2x lesson_strand active">
    <a onclick="window.open('/wwtb/api/viewer.pl?uid=demo_user&cid=1&wid=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&role=Student','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')" href="#">
        <b class="fa_text">Domain 4.OA Cluster 1 Quiz (Homework)</b>
    </a>
    <a onclick="window.open('/ePC/ePlannerAssessment.do?isbn=9780544349179&isSoar=0&toolType=12&uniqueID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&resourceBUID=NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1&nextGenTool=WB%20HTTP/1.1','_blank','toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1014,height:655,left=150,top=50,titlebar=yes')"
       href="#">
        <span id="assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1" class="assignButton" onclick="assignclicksToButton(event)">Assign</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#assignButton_NAGM15GRA4_HWK4OAC1").closest('a').css({"background-color": "red"});
```